# excluding double http from url

Tags: php, regex, xpath

i am referring this link to extract url from a webpage which contains specific words

[regex to print url from any webpage with specific word in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614589/regex-to-print-url-from-any-webpage-with-specific-word-in-url/19614956?noredirect=1#comment30598441_19614956)

but  few urls like pinterest and facebook referal url contains the words which is interested to me but i dont want to use facebook ,pinterest urls as they are not the direct url so i want to exclude these urls so i have observed that these urls will contain atleast two http

something like this

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.glamsham.com%2Fpicture-gallery%2Fsensual-in-saree-gallery%2Fspecials%2F3774%2F7%2Findex.htm&media=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glamsham.com%2Fdownload%2Fpicturegallery%2Ffeatured%2Fbollywood-beauties-saree%2F722-sensual-in-saree.jpg&guid=gNh5ehWodCZW-0&description=Rani%20Mukerji%20in%20saree%20at%20Sensual%20in%20saree%20picture%20gallery%20picture%20%23%207%20%3A%20glamsham.com

so i want to exclude urls which contains atleast two http

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links/16509122#16509122

Comment: `preg_match('/(http.*?)http/', 'https://foo.bar.baz/q=http://blah.com', $matches);` -- ungreedy matching of any two `http` with anything in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this avoid these URIs:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, '" . $needle . "')]");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
    if ( !preg_match('~^http://.+?https?\b~i', $href) )
       echo "$href\n";
}
```

`preg_match('~^http://.+?https?\b~i', $href)` should match these `to-be-excluded` URIs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links/16509122#16509122

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably check as you loop through them and remove the ones with double http's, for example:

```
$request_url ='YOUR URL';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($result); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$needle = 'blog';

$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, '" . $needle . "')]");
$validUrls = array();
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $curUrl = $node->getAttribute('href');
    if (substr_count($curUrl,'http')===1) {
        $validUrls[] = $curUrl;
    }
}

var_dump($validUrls); // all urls with only one "http"
```